# Как использовать sleep глобально?

Tags: python, asyncio, vkbottle

Есть код для бота Вконтакте:

```
import asyncio
from vkbottle.bot import Message



@bot.on.private_message(text='Таксовать')
async def taxi(message: Message):

    await message.answer('Поиск клиента...')

    await asyncio.sleep(10)

    await message.answer('Клиент найден!')
```

При отправке сообщения **"Таксовать"**, всё выполняется правильно, через 10 секунд отправляется **"Клиент найден!"**, но есть проблема, если пользователь отправит другую команду, например:**"Меню"**, то его перекинет в меню, и там уже отправится **"Клиент найден!"**, как можно реализовать что-бы другие команды не реагировали при **asyncio.sleep()**???

Comment: чем не подходит `if` к примеру?

Comment: там около 25 команд, мне к каждой делать запрос в бд?

Comment: этот вопрос нужно доработать чтобы была понятна суть, про БД ничего в вопросе нет, если это важно нужно писать в самом вопросе не в комментариях

Comment: особенно требует расшифровки сам заголовок `Как использовать sleep глобально?` что имеется в виду под глобально и каким образом `sleep` вообще зависит от команд, по сути это как искусственная задержка, но какова ее цель не ясно.

Comment: Ну тут ничего важного нету, по-моему это логично , что если надо отправлять вопрос с проверкой условия не активна ли sleep  у пользователя , но надо делать запрос в бд, не в глобальную переменную же записывать )))

Comment: то надо сделать запрос*

Comment: Глобально в плане всех команд для пользователя, а не только внутри корутины, что-бы бот полностью засыпал для пользователя.

Comment: Вы так рассуждаете как будто у Вас один пользователь этого бота, из того что Вы написали еще больше вопросов чем понимания, потратьте время на то чтобы описать свою задачу подробно и в самом вопросе, иначе Вам никто не сможет дать ответ, вопрос как я и писал выше требует доработки.

Comment: Что вам именно не понятно, вопрос описан конкретно.При использовании asyncio.sleep(), засыпает только одна функция(по факту это локальность).Мне нужно чтобы засыпал весь бот для пользователя, это асинхронный Бот и все функции и в том числе sleep, выполняются для одного пользователя.